# Why is the category item count not updating after assigning a category?

Tags: custom-taxonomy

I've created a custom category for items in the media libary. After I programmatically assign a category to an image ID, using
wp_set_object_terms( $image_id, $cat_ids, 'my-custom_category', false ), when I check the custom category page. the categories that have assigned items show zero in the count column. Is there something else that has to be done when assigning a category so its category item count will display correctly?

Comment: Out of the blue, I'd assume this only showing post count. Not images.

Comment: This could be true, but looking at the core code, I have not been able to verify this.